# How to change a field type string to array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I want to change datatype of collection without loosing any data. That datatype is inside array object.

Below is sample document where I want to change datatype of this field 'LiquidSiloNetworkId'

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: Try `{$set: { LiquidSiloNetworkId: ["$LiquidSiloNetworkId"] } }`

Comment: I tried but not working. can you suggest with complete query?

Comment: I refuse to transcript from a screenshot. Please provide also desired result.